# How to Add a Search Filter to Superset dashboard ("Directed Force Layout" visualization type)

Tags: dashboard, apache-superset

I am wondering if there is a way to add a custom search filter to a Superset dashboard. I am building a "Directed Force Layout" visualization from 25K rows and I hope to implement a search filter which limits the graphing to the specific rows meeting the search criteria (a simple text matching).

Comment: Are you trying `Filter Box`?

Answer (score 4):

Using the same table of the slice you want to filter, create a new slice with a visualization type called 'Filter Box'. Place both slice and Filter Box in the same dashboard, and then you'll be able to apply filters on the fly while you're in the dashboard view.